# is it possible to see one user control on other user control?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I got one problem, I have three user controls say Control1,control2, control3.
I want to make Control1 into 3 divs and see contol1 UI in first part 
control2-2nd part of div
Control3- in 3 Part of div

Is it possible?
I wanted to do this just for the sake i can maintain with less code .Is there any alternative .other this which will suit me best.
Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put multiple user control on a single user control. However your question is down voted the solution of your problem is as given below :

Create a sample website. Add Webusercontrol1.ascx ,Webusercontrol2.ascx, Webusercontrol3.ascx, Webusercontrol4.ascx in it and modify the code as given below.

**Default.aspx page html**

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SO_1._Default" %>
<%@ Register src="WebUserControl1.ascx" tagname="WebUserControl1" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <uc1:WebUserControl1 ID="WebUserControl11" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

UserControl-1 Html : This is container user control and this will have all required user control on it.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs"
Inherits="SO_1.WebUserControl1" %>
<%@ Register Src="WebUserControl1.ascx" TagName="WebUserControl2" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register Src="WebUserControl2.ascx" TagName="WebUserControl2" TagPrefix="uc2" %>
<%@ Register Src="WebUserControl3.ascx" TagName="WebUserControl3" TagPrefix="uc3" %>
<%@ Register Src="WebUserControl4.ascx" TagName="WebUserControl4" TagPrefix="uc4" %>
<p>
    <b>DIV-1 Container User control</b></p>
<div>
    <b>DIV1</b>
    <br />
    <uc2:WebUserControl2 ID="WebUserControl21" runat="server" />
</div>
<div>
    <b>DIV2</b>
    <br />
    <uc3:WebUserControl3 ID="WebUserControl31" runat="server" />
</div>
<div>
    <b>DIV3</b>
    <br />
    <uc4:WebUserControl4 ID="WebUserControl41" runat="server" />
</div>
```

UserControl-2 html

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl2.ascx.cs" Inherits="SO_1.WebUserControl2" %>
User Control-1
```

UserControl-3 html

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl2.ascx.cs" Inherits="SO_1.WebUserControl2" %>
User Control-2
```

UserControl-4 html

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl2.ascx.cs" Inherits="SO_1.WebUserControl2" %>
User Control-3
```